# SQL find total count of each type in a column

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and am stumped on what should be a simple query. I have a table with the following pattern:

```
Id |  Type  
------------
1  |  Red   
2  |  Blue  
3  |  Blue  
4  |  Red   
..
```

I would like to write a query to return a table that counts the total number of instances of each type and returns a table with the following pattern, for example, if 'Blue' occurs in 12 rows, and 'Red' occurs in 16 rows in the table above, the result would be:

```
Blue | Red 
-----------
 12  |  16
```

Comment: Just put the values in separate rows and use `group by`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Type
```

If you'd like to see the Types in separate columns, you could do this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Blue, SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is a really great solution, thanks! I ran it against a prod table with more than 50+ columns including few blob ones and all text columns are NVarchar2 datatype, but using this on more than few columns itself has a huge impact on query exec time.
@Will can you please suggest an optimal approach to run value-wise count as a column for this kind of tables?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ***count over partition by***.  Here's a code I wrote to help my company check for duplicate Technician EmployeeID's and Pincodes, including count and YES/NO columns to allow filtering in excel so they can see what corrections need to be made:

```
select 
    t.TechnicianId, t.TechnicianName, t.Pincode, t.EmployeeID
    , [Pincode Count] = count(t.Pincode) over (partition by t.Pincode)
    , [Duplicate Pincode?] = case count(t.Pincode) over (partition by t.Pincode) when 1 then 'NO' else 'YES' end
    , [EmployeeID Count] = count(t.EmployeeID) over (partition by t.EmployeeID)
    , [Duplicate EmployeeID?] = case count(t.EmployeeID) over (partition by t.EmployeeID) when 1 then 'NO' else 'YES' end
from Technicians t
group by t.TechnicianId, t.TechnicianName, t.Pincode, t.EmployeeID
order by 4
```