# How to count the amount of entry in a column separated by a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a table as my database, and I want to create a Bar Chart to of out the Reasons Column. This is an example of my table:

Table Name: Survey

| id | reasons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c |
| 2 | a,d,e |
| 3 | b,c,d |

How to count total amount of each reasons like this table below?

| reasons | total |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 1 |
| e | 1 |

Comment: If you fix your design, this is trivial.

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows), [SQL find total count of each type in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595456/sql-find-total-count-of-each-type-in-a-column)

Comment: any suggestion to on how to fix it?

Comment: *"any suggestion to on how to fix it?"* Look into the basic principles behind normalisation and one to many relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `string_split()`:

```
select s.value as reason, count(*)
from t cross apply
     string_split(reasons, ',') s
group by s.value
order by s.value;
```

That said, you should fix your data model.  You should have a separate table with one row per reason.